# How can I rotate a texture around a mesh with nodes?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-coordinates

I downloaded a marble material for my project and when I applied it on some of the faces it doesn't follow the face's normals.

I UV unwrapped all my meshes I want the texture on, tried different nodes, but nothing seemed to solve the problem.

The pillars are all separated objects on the picture below.

[image]

My shading node setup looks like this:

[image]

If I connect it to a UV node or the UV point of the texture coordinate the biger faces (like the floor) will get pixelated even tho only the floor and all faces facing Z or -Z axis are good.

By pixelated I mean it will look like this:

[image]

When I say the texture doesn't follow the face rotation I mean something like this. It's a beveled edge and as you can see the faces facing Z or -Z axis are perfect, but as it rotates more and more to faceing X/-X/Y/-Y direction (basically rotating 90 degrees) it will get more and more streched.

[image]

And this is how a UV map looks on a pillar (all the same on each pillar)

[image]

If you could help it would be much appriciated!

Comment: First thing, you need to use the UV output of the Texture Coordinate if you plan to use the UV unwrap

Comment: I tried, but with that biger areas (faces) like the line on the ground will get pixelated, like if it zoomes in on the texture a LOT. Another problem with that is this way all the pillars would look the same.

Comment: please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file (only one pillar): https://pasteall.org/blend/ (copy paste and share the URL)

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/c0b66dc8a2b54a5c8fa7127eb265475d

Sorry it took a while I used this method for the first time

Comment: when you say that "it doesn't follow the face's normals", what do you mean, could you please show some screenshots? Also show the faces that get pixellated.

Comment: I edited the question, added two new screenshots, I hope this helps

Comment: What you can do is use the Box setting instead of Flat in the Image Texture node, not sure why you don't prefer the UV outpur though, it should not get pixellated if the unwrap is good

Comment: YES!!! This worked, this was a life saver, thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the *Box* setting instead of *Flat* in the *Image Texture* node, it will project the texture on the 3 axis:

[image]